# Android, landscape only view orientation - Phone and Tablet

Tags: android, view, orientation, landscape

I'm trying to create an android app with a fixed landscape orientation so I updated the manifest to include the following

activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"

This worked perfectly on a Pixel 2 phone, but when I opened the app on a Nexus 9 Tablet the orientation matched the rotation of the device as if I had done nothing.

Why is this happening and what can I do to resolve the issue?

I'm fairly novice, so please keep things simple.

cheers

Comment: you didnt post what you have done.

Comment: haha thanks, the code was surround by <> which messed with things.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

to your OnCreate method and see what happens